# How can I fix this error in the ULS logs: ERROR: Failed to OpenThreadToken, LastError=1008?

Tags: uls

I'm constantly getting this error since yesterday afternoon on the WFE box. No one was creating a site or anything. I'm running SharePoint 2010 with SP1.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure, no one tried to create a site? What about mysite self creation?